# How much is loot reduced for raiding lower Town Halls?

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image]

I am thinking of upgrading my Town Hall to level 10. I am bored of upgrading my walls. In info while upgrading my Town Hall it says upgrading Town Hall would provide less loot from lower Town Halls, but **how much less loot**?. If the effect of loot reduction after upgrading my Town Hall is less then I would upgrade my Town Hall. Does anybody know how much loot is reduced for lower Town Halls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a page on [www.clashofclans.wikia.com](http://www.clashofclans.wikia.com) that states

> Town Hall Difference - Percentage of Loot Available
>
> Same or higher Level - 100%
>
> 1 level lower - 80%
>
> 2 levels lower - 50%
>
> 3 levels lower - 25%

The difference is your TH level vs their TH level, so if your TH is higher you get a penalty.

Comment: Can You please give the link to page also

Comment: link is now in the answer to the general site, you can use the search function there to find the specific page.